# Unable to Download Application - at AppStore, after new app version

Tags: ios, app-store

I just sent a new release of my app to AppStore and it was approved today.

But in very few devices when I'm trying to update by the AppStore, when it is installing the progress bar goes until the end, but when finish, it shows the message:

```
Unable to Download Application
<AppName> could not be installed at this time.
```

I'm worried if this can be a problem with my code or an issue form AppStore.

From the code, this app uses CoreData, but there's no change in the CoreData, only small enhancements

What really make me worried is that only few devices (2 at this moment) had this problem, and I tried in different networks and over 3G.

Does anybody has any idea? can it be an App problem?

Comment: Does it seem to happen when downloading the new *version* of the app, or when installing on a device without *any* version?

Comment: its when I'm downloading the new version.

Comment: most of devices it worked ok, but there are two with this problem, when upgrading the app version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably an App Store problem.

You say you are worried about Core Data - but Core Data doesn't even matter before you *install* the app.

Comment: Maybe.. but the during all day it didnt work.. and only few devices that it happens... most devices worked ok...